# jQuery ui resizable breaks for nw handle when aspect ratio is true and containment parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to implement jquery ui resizable for a child element with custom handles.
I have successfully implemented the functionality using the following code

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
 margin:40px;
}

.parent {
  background: yellow;
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
}

.ui-resizable-ne,
.ui-resizable-se,
.ui-resizable-nw,
.ui-resizable-sw,
.ui-resizable-n,
.ui-resizable-s,
.ui-resizable-w,
.ui-resizable-e {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 9px !important;
  height: 9px !important;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
  background-image: none !important;
  right: -5px !important;
  bottom: -5px !important;
}

.ui-resizable-n,
.ui-resizable-s {
  left: 50% !important;
  margin-left: -5px !important;
}

.ui-resizable-e,
.ui-resizable-w {
  top: 50% !important;
  margin-top: -5px !important;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $(".child").resizable({
     aspectRatio:true,              
     minWidth:100,
     maxWidth:$(".parent").width(),                     
     containment:"parent",
     handles:"all"
 });
```

But my problem is when i am trying to resize with the nw handle it breaks the aspect ratio as i move it to left most corner of the parent.

I am not finding any problem with other handles but only with nw handle.

I am using the latest jquery and jquery ui version.

Live demo - http://jsbin.com/OJolIKA/1/edit

is their any bug in the jquery ui resizable or am i doing anything work?

please help me to have a solution for this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem for one of my projects and worked around it. [Here is my solution](http://jsbin.com/OJolIKA/20/edit?html,css,js,output).

You need to place child with position:absolute and assign 5px padding to parent. Then on being resized function, just look for top or left going near to bounds. I checked it to be 3px away from bounds. As soon as this situation occurs just fire mouse up event, so resize is stopped.
Just before this capture top and left position of the child. So that you can reposition it to last place just before mouse up.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem using resizable on an element within a relatively positioned parent, aspect ratio true, containment by the parent, and defined max width and height. the behavior was slightly different in that the child element would jump in size erratically.

What worked for me was to also define max-width and max-height CSS values for the element to be resized before calling $.resizable()

Maybe this will help someone else.